# Install latest version of tex

Tags: latex, texlive

I am trying to install `texlive-full` from the terminal. I issued two commands.

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-full
sudo apt-get update
```

I also tried -

```
sudo apt-get upgrade texlive-full
```

Despite of all of this I've only got 2015 version of `texlive` (which is very old). Why my terminal is not allowing me to install the latest version of this package? Is there any way to specifically say that `install version 2019`? I've tried searching for the version number of the 2019 release but couldn't find it. Even the number which I get as the output of `tex -version` is -

```
TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2015/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.2.1
```

How to get the latest version of `texlive`?

Comment: You haven't told us what release - https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=texlive shows versions for each release ; my guess is you're using the 2016-April release of Ubuntu so it seems appropriate.

Comment: Yes your guess is right, I'm not complaining about the defaults of ubuntu packages, but please let me know how to install the latest version of texlive even when I'm using ubuntu 16.4

Comment: A quick search turned up [this guide](https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html). ...was really easy to find.

Comment: Use [this ppa repository](https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/texlive). You will install a much newer version than 2015, though it might not be the latest. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When Ubuntu 19.10 is released later this month it will have the 2019 version of texlive-full in its default repositories. The texlive-full package installs a large amount of dependencies along with it, but it installs seamlessly if you install it from the default Ubuntu repositories with `sudo apt install texlive-full`. You are currently using 16.04 which is getting old enough to consider the clean package management advantage of installing the latest version. Logical package management is more important than marginal improvements in the latest version of one application for most Ubuntu users.

For installing TeX Live over the internet, the official [Tex Live website](https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html) recommends starting the TeX Live installation by downloading [install-tl-unx.tar.gz](http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-unx.tar.gz) (4MB). The rest of the Tex Live files (~2GB) will be installed over the network.

Comment: So how to install texlive 2019 now?